JetBrains IntelliJ/WebStorm, how to persist environment variables across all tests runners
I am using IntelliJ and/or WebStorm. I'm working on an app that have hundreds of tests (Jest). Theses tests need environment variable to run (stored in .env.test file).
Every time I start a new test by clicking the little arrow in the file, I have to reconfigure all the environment variables by clicking "modify run configuration". I can't find a place where say "For this project, please use these env var".
It's probably obvious but I can't find it anywhere.

Every Run/Debug Configuration is standalone -- there is no "shared config" kind of fields. But you can edit defaults that will be used when a Run Configuration is created -- see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration.html#templates NOTE that changing the default values of a template does not affect already existing run/debug configurations.

Can't you just require the env var from your .env.test file  in jest.config.ts, and there map the env var to the process?

Thanks to LazyOne, I updated the default config in Run | Edit Configurations.
Then Edit Configuration Templates, then Jest and i changed it like this:

